# How To Create Shared Dll Using SQLite Amalgamation?

Tags: visual-c++, sqlite, mfc

I can download of source code SQLite Amalgamation and
How I make x86 and x64 bit lib files?

Answer (score 0):

I can Find out another solution. how build static library ?
then this library to used in Visual Studio project.

1. Download of Source Code [Sqlite Source Code](http://www.sqlite.org/2014/sqlite-amalgamation-3080401.zip)
2. After extract Folder Copy following files 
   [image]
3. create project On visual studio
4. Win32 -> Win32 Project
5. Next -> Select Static Library -> Empty Project
6. Finish
7. Open Project Folder and paste sqlite files on project folder
8. after right click on project folder in visual studio and select add existing items
9. after include all files.
10. after build release mode (x86 and x64)

Answer (score 0):

I have done exactly this. First of all, I can see that your question is tagged as visual-c++. The compiler is still not supporting the long files (with the number of lines greater than 65535). Therefore you need to split the sqlite source using a split-sqlite3c.tcl script available at [SQLite website](http://www.sqlite.org/src/artifact/d9be87f1c34028). See [here](http://sqlite.org:8080/cgi-bin/mailman/private/sqlite-users/2012-March/037690.html) my question to SQLite user group and D Richard Hipp's answer:

> Instructions from D. Richard Hipp:
>   http://sqlite.org:8080/cgi-bin/mailman/private/sqlite-users/2012-March/037690.html
>
> Get a copy of the
>   split-sqlite3c.tclhttp://www.sqlite.org/src/artifact/d9be87f1c34028script and a copy of the amalgamation.  Run
>
> ```
> tclsh split-sqlite3c.tcl
> ```
>
> You may need to install tclsh from
>   http://www.activestate.com/activetcl
>
> The script above will produce these files:
>
> ```
> sqlite3-all.c
> sqlite3-1.c
> sqlite3-2.c
> sqlite3-3.c
> sqlite3-4.c
> sqlite3-5.c
> ```
>
> You compile with sqlite3-all.c and it will #include all the others.
>   --  D. Richard Hipp drh at sqlite.org

Please note that you only need to split the files for debug builds. For the release builds just use the source from amalgamation.

I have created a VC project that depending on the configuration (Debug or Release) uses the either version (split or not split). Here is the project file (vcxproj) source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{A39019F1-A5BD-4A44-9BD4-D01391E975F1}</ProjectGuid>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    <RootNamespace>SQLib3Am</RootNamespace>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>StaticLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>StaticLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>NotUsing</PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;_LIB;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
    </Link>
    <Lib>
      <MinimumRequiredVersion>5.00</MinimumRequiredVersion>
    </Lib>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <PrecompiledHeader>NotUsing</PrecompiledHeader>
      <Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;NDEBUG;_LIB;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
    </Link>
    <Lib>
      <MinimumRequiredVersion>5.00</MinimumRequiredVersion>
    </Lib>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="sqlite3.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="sqlite3ext.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="shell.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="sqlite3-1.c">
      <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">true</ExcludedFromBuild>
      <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">true</ExcludedFromBuild>
    </ClCompile>
    <ClCompile Include="sqlite3-2.c">
      <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">true</ExcludedFromBuild>
      <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">true</ExcludedFromBuild>
    </ClCompile>
    <ClCompile Include="sqlite3-3.c">
      <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">true</ExcludedFromBuild>
      <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">true</ExcludedFromBuild>
    </ClCompile>
    <ClCompile Include="sqlite3-4.c">
      <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">true</ExcludedFromBuild>
      <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">true</ExcludedFromBuild>
    </ClCompile>
    <ClCompile Include="sqlite3-5.c">
      <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">true</ExcludedFromBuild>
      <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">true</ExcludedFromBuild>
    </ClCompile>
    <ClCompile Include="sqlite3-all.c">
      <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">true</ExcludedFromBuild>
    </ClCompile>
    <ClCompile Include="sqlite3.c">
      <ExcludedFromBuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">true</ExcludedFromBuild>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="sqlite3.def" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

To use the above source, create a folder and create an empty file in this folder with a vcxproj extension. Put the above source into this file. Copy the sqlite source from amalgamation into the same folder. Copy the tcl script into the same folder and run it to split the files. Now, open the vcxproj file with Visual Studio (double click) and compile. You will have your lib files.

Please note that the file is for VC2010. But you can convert it to a later version very easily.